# Converting musicg spectrogram output to dBFS

Tags: spectrogram, dbfs

I'm trying to convert musicg Spectrogram output to dBFS.

With 16-bit signed integer PCM audio, and an FFT length of 2048, I'm trying to analyze the spectrogram for an audio file to determine things like "Was a particular frequency notched out by equalization" or "Was the audio high-passed or low-passed" by looking for peaks in the spectrogram.

I'm taking a normalized musicg spectrogram, and converting the magnitude values to dBFS (max value: 0 dBFS) by doing:

```
dBFS = (20 * Math.log10( 2 * Math.abs(magnitude) / 2048)) - 100
```

I think this is giving me what I'm looking for, and it correlates closely to what I'm seeing in other tools.  And if I decrease the gain on a file by 20db, and then analyze the decreased file, the dBFS data I get back is 20db less than the original.

However, I noticed that when I [view the spectrogram in Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/plot_spectrum.html) (using plot spectrum), the dB values in Audacity seem to range between 4db and 9db higher than what I'm getting from musicg and the above equation.

**Is there something I'm doing particularly wrong in the way I'm trying to calculate dBFS from the musicg absolute spectrogram data?**  (or perhaps I'm mistaken and what I'm calculating, and what Audacity is displaying, are not quite the same thing)

Comment: Where does the -100 come from ? I expect it should be -96 (full scale for 16 bit audio) ?

Comment: You know there is a HUGE difference between **spectrogram** and **spectrum**?

Comment: The -100 came from thinking that since the db scale max is  100, I should subtract 100 to put the values with 0 as the highest possible value.  But since the full scale max for 16 bit audio is 96db, that makes sense to subtract 96, instead of 100.

Comment: jojek, thanks for reminding me of the different between a spectrogram and a spectrum.  I expected to find peaks in the spectrogram data equal to the peaks in the spectrum - I guess I did find that, +/- 5dBFS (using -96).